# Spring Cache - Clear cache only when API response is success

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

I am using Spring Cache  `@CacheEvict` & `@Cacheable`

Currently I am running a scheduler every Hr to clear cache and next time when fetchUser() is called it will fetch data from external APi and add to cache.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *}")
@CacheEvict(value = "some-unique-value", allEntries = true)
public void clearUserCache() {
    log.info("Cache cleared");
}

@Cacheable(value = "some-unique-value", unless = "#result.isFailure()")
@Override
public Result<UserResponse> fetchUser() {
    try {
        UserResponse userResponse = api.fetchUserDetail();
        return Result.success(userResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Result.failure(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Now what we need is to clear cache only when User API call is success. Is there a way to do that.

As now cache is cleared on schedule and suppose external API call fails. Main API will return error response. In that case I should be able to use existing cache itself.

Comment: While evicting the cache, you are not making any API call to check the API call success or failure explicitly. How you would capture its status? API call method using `@Cacheable` that means, it will read from the cache, it will not make actual Rest Call. Am I correct?

Comment: Scheduler is not trigger point for User API call. It will be called from Service using userAPI and only when that service is triggered by external system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any direct implementation but with a work around I was able to do it.

**Use Case**

- User API response should be updated only when next service call is triggered which make use of User API. It should not be updated by scheduler. As we need to pass on header information coming in from external system, to User API as well.
- Cache must be cleared only when User API response is success.

**Steps:**

- Added a variable in scheduler and turning it `ON` on Schedule time and `OFF` when cache is updated.
- This flag is used in `UserService` class to check if scheduler was triggered or not.
- If not, use cache. If `true`, trigger User API call. Check for response, if success. Trigger `CacheEvict` method and update Cache.

**Sample Code:**

*SchedulerConfig*

```
private boolean updateUserCache;

@Scheduled(cron = "${0 0 * * * *}") // runs every Hr
public void userScheduler() {
    updateUserCache = true;
    log.info("Scheduler triggered for User");
}

@CacheEvict(value = "USER_CACHE", allEntries = true)
public void clearUserCache() {
    updateUserCache = false;
    log.info("User cache cleared");
}

public boolean isUserCacheUpdateRequired() {
    return updateUserCache;
}
```

*UserService*

```
UserResponse userResponse = null;
if (schedulerConfig.isUserCacheUpdateRequired()) {
    userResponse = userCache.fetchUserDetail(); 
    if (userResponse != null) {
        // clear's cache and userResponse is stored in cache automatically when getUserDetail is called below
        schedulerConfig.clearUserCache(); 
    }
}
return userCache.getUserDetail(userResponse);
```

*UserCache*

```
@Cacheable(value = "USER_CACHE", key = "#root.targetClass", unless = "#result.isFailure()")
public Result<User> getUserDetail(UserResponse userResponse) {
    try {
        if (userResponse == null) { // handle first time trigger when cache is not available
            userResponse = fetchUserDetail(); // actual API call 
        }
        return Result.success(mapToUser(userResponse));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Result.failure("Error Response");
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- Result is a custom Wrapper, assume it as a object which has success or failure attributes
- I had to add `@Cacheable` part as separate Bean because caching only works on proxy objects. If I keep `getUserDetail` inside `UserService` and call directly, its not been intercepted as proxy and cache logic is not working, API call is triggered each time.
- Most important: This is not the best solution and has scope for improvement.

Comment: looks bit complicated.. did you come across any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, why don't you call it as a normal method after checking the API call is correct at this method's parent?

With your code, something along the lines of

```java
// we just leave scheduled here as you need it.
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *}")
@CacheEvict(value = "some-unique-value", allEntries = true)
public void clearUserCache() {
    log.info("Cache cleared");
}

@Cacheable(value = "some-unique-value", unless = "#result.isFailure()")
@Override
public Result<UserResponse> fetchUser() {
    try {
        UserResponse userResponse = api.fetchUserDetail();
        return Result.success(userResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Result.failure(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

public void parentMethod() {
    Result<UserResponse> userResult = this.fetchUser();
    if(userResult.isFailure()) {
        this.clearUserCache();
    }
}
```

This way, if any `Exception` is thrown it will return with a `failure` status and you're able to check it. So the cache will be cleared either **every hour** or **when it didn't work**.

So the next time, as it was a failure and there's no cache, it will try again.

Comment: Just a little deviation.  Only catch is you will never reach "this.clearUserCache();"  if cache is already in place. Spring will return proxy Object instead of calling actual method.

Comment: Also scheduler is required as data need to refresh post every Hr by any subsequent API call.

Comment: I fixed my answer. The parent will call `this.fetchUser()` and if **the previous iteration** didn't work, or it passed an hour, it will call the method again. 

Or do you need to check it against the current iteration?

Comment: 2 deviations  1. If cache is cleared at every Hr and UserAPI is down overall response will fail. Which defeat the purpose.
2. parentMethod() should not be void and check is if(!userResult.isFailure()) {  you missed "not" I guess.
But over all its in align with what I implemented. will be posting soon. Thanks.